# Is DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS transaction safe?

Tags: sql-server

I executed `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` before executing `CHECKPOINT` only to kill the executing query in between when i realised I could have dirty pages in the memory. It is recommended to run `CHECKPOINT` before `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` to write any dirty pages to disk. Since it was a blackbox machine and I would have no idea as to what data was cached , Would I have lost any data even though I stopped the query completion?

Comment: Note the `CLEAN` in the name. Dirty pages are not part of clean buffers and `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` will not affect them. The `CHECKPOINT` is a perf/functional optimization to make sure as many buffers are clean as possible (since you use this for cold cache testing), not a necessity to guarantee correctness. Except for `SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT`, `DBCC PAGE` and tripping SQL Server bugs, I don't think there's anything you can do in T-SQL that will cause data loss, and certainly if `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` could do it that would be a bug that I'd expect someone to address somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It will not be a problem. `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` only drops the clean buffers from the buffer cache. Dirty pages (modified pages) will not be dropped by `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`.

On the other hand, `CHECKPOINT` writes the dirty pages(modified pages) to disk. So, it is not going to work with Clean buffers in buffer cache.

Generally, it is recommended to first issue `CHECKPOINT` to write dirty pages to disk, so that, there will be only clean buffers in the buffer cache.Then issue `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`, which drops all the buffers in the buffer cache.

You can read more on this at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-dropcleanbuffers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)